# Abrir el contenido de una carpeta desde pyhton

Tags: python

Tengo que buscar en una carpeta especifica imágenes de tipo DICOM que se corresponde a un paciente determinado y me genere un archivo csv.

El problema lo tengo en que, una vez abierta la carpeta con los fichero DICOM no se como acceder al contenido para que me busque dicho paciente.

por ahora lo que tengo es esto:

```
from os import listdir
for cosa in listdir("C:\\Users\anonio\Desktop\ImagenesDICOM"):
    print (cosa)
```

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema alguna respuesta, @liz? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 2):

[**DICOM**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM) no es un formato soportado nativamente por Python, por lo que lo más sencillo es integrar algún paquete que lo soporte, el que pareciera más maduro es [**Pydicom**](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/index.html), la lectura básica de una imagen de este tipo no tiene gran dificultad:

```
import glob
import pydicom

for file in glob.glob("C:/Users/anonio/Desktop/ImagenesDICOM/*.dcm"):
    ds = pydicom.dcmread(file)
    print(ds.PatientName)
```

Comentarios extra:

- En primer lugar, por las dudas, para instalar [**Pydicom**](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/index.html), deberemos ejecutar `pip install pydicom`
- Usamos `glob.glob()` para obtener una lista de archivos que cumplan con el patrón `C:/Users/anonio/Desktop/ImagenesDICOM/*.dcm`
- `PatientName` entiendo por la documentación que es el atributo con el cual accedemos a la etiqueta del nombre del paciente.
- [Aquí](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/pydicom_user_guide.html) la guía de usuario del paquete

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, me gusta lo completa que es +1.

Answer (score 0):

La cadena o string correspondiente a el path que estas accediendo está mal escrito.

El *backslash* o `\` se escribe `\\` dentro de los string de python, dado que el primero es un símbolo especial de python. Como se explica más específicamente [aquí](https://www.pitt.edu/~naraehan/python2/tutorial7.html).

En conclusión, la ruta debe ser:

```
"C:\\Users\\anonio\\Desktop\\ImagenesDICOM"
```